22.04 latest kernel upgrade VMware fails to build kernel modules
Using Software Updater security updates, I updated to latest production kernel Software Updater requested me to do -- all automatically through Software Updater.  I have done this many times, and each time when invoking vmware, vmware automatically (re)builds two kernel modules that the type 2 hypervisor needs.  This time, the build failed.  VMware is the current production release.  I have the relevant VMware build logfile that contains the failure information, but Ask Ubuntu does not seem to have a mechanism to attach that text file as a displayed choice of the Ask Ubuntu web browser user interface.  I am pasting this input into this question on the assumption that the Ask Ubuntu "editors" will appropriately manipulate the file for this forum.  I used the curly braces on the UI, used gvim to open, select all, and copy, the then pasted over the enter code here (blue overtint) to include the relevant log file below.  Any help would be appreciated.  As I stated, this has not happened to me except when the kernel posted to Update Software (production, not testing) had a software defect that Ubuntu (eventually) fixed.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 Log for VMware Workstation pid=22448 version=17.5.2 build=build-23775571 option=Release
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 The host is x86_64.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 Host is Linux 6.8.0-40-generic Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS Ubuntu 22.04 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 Host offset from UTC is -07:00.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/ykarant/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/ykarant/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.313Z In(05) host-22448 PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/ykarant/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.378Z Wa(03) host-22448 Logging to /tmp/vmware-ykarant/vmware-22448.log
2024-08-17T07:32:47.384Z In(05) host-22448 Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.384Z In(05) host-22448 Created new pathsHash.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.384Z In(05) host-22448 Setting header path for 6.8.0-40-generic to "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.384Z In(05) host-22448 Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.384Z In(05) host-22448 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-08-17T07:32:47.384Z In(05) host-22448 /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.384Z In(05) host-22448 using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
2024-08-17T07:32:47.390Z In(05) host-22448 Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.390Z In(05) host-22448 The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2024-08-17T07:32:47.576Z In(05) host-22448 found symbol version file /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers
2024-08-17T07:32:47.576Z In(05) host-22448 Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.587Z In(05) host-22448 Read 28974 symbol versions
2024-08-17T07:32:47.587Z In(05) host-22448 Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.587Z In(05) host-22448 Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.587Z In(05) host-22448 Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.590Z In(05) host-22448 "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.590Z In(05) host-22448 Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.592Z In(05) host-22448 "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.600Z In(05) host-22448 to be installed: vmmon status: 0
2024-08-17T07:32:47.600Z In(05) host-22448 to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2024-08-17T07:32:47.613Z In(05) host-22448 Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.613Z In(05) host-22448 Setting header path for 6.8.0-40-generic to "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.613Z In(05) host-22448 Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.613Z In(05) host-22448 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-08-17T07:32:47.613Z In(05) host-22448 /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.613Z In(05) host-22448 using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
2024-08-17T07:32:47.619Z In(05) host-22448 Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.619Z In(05) host-22448 The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2024-08-17T07:32:47.807Z In(05) host-22448 found symbol version file /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers
2024-08-17T07:32:47.807Z In(05) host-22448 Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.818Z In(05) host-22448 Read 28974 symbol versions
2024-08-17T07:32:47.819Z In(05) host-22448 Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include
2024-08-17T07:32:47.819Z In(05) host-22448 Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include
2024-08-17T07:32:47.819Z In(05) host-22448 Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.819Z In(05) host-22448 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-08-17T07:32:47.819Z In(05) host-22448 /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.819Z In(05) host-22448 using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
2024-08-17T07:32:47.825Z In(05) host-22448 Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.825Z In(05) host-22448 The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2024-08-17T07:32:47.826Z In(05) host-22448 Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2024-08-17T07:32:47.828Z In(05) host-22448 Got gcc version "11".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.828Z In(05) host-22448 GCC major version 11 does not match Kernel GCC major version 12.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.828Z In(05) host-22448 Attempting to use a compiler at location "/usr/bin/gcc-12".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.829Z In(05) host-22448 Got gcc version "12".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.829Z In(05) host-22448 The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.830Z In(05) host-22448 Got gcc version "12".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.830Z In(05) host-22448 The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.832Z In(05) host-22448 Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.832Z In(05) host-22448 No matching PBM set was found for kernel "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.832Z In(05) host-22448 The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.832Z In(05) host-22448 Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.832Z In(05) host-22448 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-08-17T07:32:47.832Z In(05) host-22448 /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2024-08-17T07:32:47.832Z In(05) host-22448 using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
2024-08-17T07:32:47.838Z In(05) host-22448 Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:47.838Z In(05) host-22448 The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2024-08-17T07:32:50.427Z In(05) host-22448 The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2024-08-17T07:32:50.427Z In(05) host-22448 Validating path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for kernel release "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:50.427Z In(05) host-22448 Failed to find /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2024-08-17T07:32:50.427Z In(05) host-22448 /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2024-08-17T07:32:50.427Z In(05) host-22448 using /usr/bin/gcc-12 for preprocess check
2024-08-17T07:32:50.442Z In(05) host-22448 Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "6.8.0-40-generic".
2024-08-17T07:32:50.442Z In(05) host-22448 The header path "/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include" for the kernel "6.8.0-40-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2024-08-17T07:32:50.443Z In(05) host-22448 Using temp dir "/tmp".
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 Stopping VMware services:
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448    VMware Authentication Daemon[71G done
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448    Virtual machine monitor[71G done
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/moduleloop.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/sharedAreaVmmon.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/statVarsVmmon.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/task.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/bootstrap/bootstrap.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/bootstrap/vmmblob.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/driver.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/hub.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/userif.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/netif.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/bridge.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/procfs.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/smac.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   MODPOST /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/Module.symvers
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   BTF [M] /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 [AppLoader] Use shipped Linux kernel AIO access library.
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 An up-to-date "libaio" or "libaio1" package from your system is preferred.
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 [AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 Using kernel build system.
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o: warning: objtool: CrossPage_CodePage+0x207: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o] Error 255
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[3]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o'
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Add() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Remove()
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Remove() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Test()
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/task.c:548:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘TaskGetFlatWriteableDataSegment’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   548 | TaskGetFlatWriteableDataSegment(void)
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 In file included from /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:52:
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 ./arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h: In function ‘random_get_entropy’:
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 ./arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:12:24: error: implicit declaration of function ‘random_get_entropy_fallback’; did you mean ‘random_get_entropy’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448    12 |                 return random_get_entropy_fallback();
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       |                        random_get_entropy
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c: At top level:
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:700:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘Vmx86FreeVMDriver’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   700 | Vmx86FreeVMDriver(VMDriver *vm)
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:733:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘Vmx86AllocVMDriver’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   733 | Vmx86AllocVMDriver(uint32 numVCPUs)
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:2926:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘HostIFCheckTrackedMPN’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448  2926 | HostIFCheckTrackedMPN(VMDriver *vm, // IN: The VM instance
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3046:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘HostIFWritePhysicalWork’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448  3046 | HostIFWritePhysicalWork(MA ma,             // MA to be written to
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3205:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘HostIFStartTimer’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448  3205 | HostIFStartTimer(Bool rateChanged,  //IN: Did rate change?
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:271:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘LinuxDriverInit’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   271 | LinuxDriverInit(void)
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:339:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘LinuxDriverExit’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   339 | LinuxDriverExit(void)
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o] Error 1
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic/Makefile:1926: /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmmon-only] Error 2
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 make: *** [Makefile:117: vmmon.ko] Error 2
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 Using kernel build system.
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/netif.c:173:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘VNetNetIf_Create’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   173 | VNetNetIf_Create(char *devName,  // IN:
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.c:87:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘VNetUserListener_Create’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448    87 | VNetUserListener_Create(uint32 classMask,  // IN: the listener's class mask
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/userif.c:1091:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘VNetUserIf_Create’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448  1091 | VNetUserIf_Create(VNetPort **ret) // OUT
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/bridge.c:258:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘VNetBridge_Create’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448   258 | VNetBridge_Create(const char *devName, // IN:  name of device (e.g., "eth0")
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/bridge.c:1411:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘VNetBridgeSendLargePacket’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448  1411 | VNetBridgeSendLargePacket(struct sk_buff *skb,        // IN: packet to split
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/userif.o: warning: objtool: VNetCsumAndCopyToUser+0x2d: call to csum_partial_copy_nocheck() with UACCESS enabled
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/modconfig-hgXpRk/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
2024-08-17T07:32:58.827Z In(05) host-22448 


From your log: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.

maybe related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773558/vmware-vmmon-vmnet-17-5-1-and-linux-kernel-6-8-0-wont-compile

From above:
maybe related unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773558/… –
nobody
Commented yesterday
The above works.
` unzip vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.5.1.zip
cd vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.5.1/
make
make install
/etc/init.d/vmware restart `

Another solution is to remove VMWare player and install VMWare Workstation Pro 17.6 which is free for personal use.
sudo vmware-installer --uninstall-product vmware-player
(I kept the config files)

cd Downloads

chmod +x VMware-Workstation-Full-*.bundle

sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-*.bundle

